# C Code Compilation Errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile the following exploit: http://code.google.com/p/rootkit-for-linux/source/browse/trunk/vmsplice.c?spec=svn2&r=2

However, I get the following errors when compiling it on CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

$ gcc  local.c
/tmp/ccOO1kwW.o: In function `main':
local.c:(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to`loader_end'
local.c:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `loader_start'
local.c:(.text+0x264): undefined reference to`loader_start'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If you look at the trunk, there's an assembly file that probably defines the `loader_start` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're trying to compile the file by itself. Try downloading the entire source listing and use this Makefile they provided:

http://code.google.com/p/rootkit-for-linux/source/browse/trunk/Makefile?r=2

```
obj-m := test.o
test-y = main.o


KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)


default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

r3: clean
        gcc -o rookit -g -D_DEBUG_ vmsplice.c asm.S
        objdump -d rookit > rookit.s

test: clean
        gcc -o test -g -D_TEST_ asm.S test.c
        objdump -d test > test.s

clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.ko
```

Comment: Yep, there are some assembly files there that you probably need to link against.